# Opa being annoyingly magical (database persistence issue)

Tags: mongodb, opa

I just spent the weekend starting to learn Opa and getting it setup. It's loaded with amazing features and I really want to use it effectively, however on my very first tutorial, things went very odd. I simply copied the Hello, database program and compiled it. I didn't specify a remote db when I ran the test.js file the first time, and so opa used a local one. However, I was already running a mongodb server on localhost that I wanted to use, so I specified it as --db-remote and tried again. The counter stayed the same though, even after removing the local database files that opa had made, and the data files from my mongodb server. Somewhere, somehow, Opa is storing that counter and I can't find out where.

Important Information (My setup):
I'm running Windows 7, where I have mongoDB setup and running on localhost.
I am then running the Opa vagrant VM inside of Windows.

Even with the localhost mongoDB server shutdown, and ensuring Opa doesn't use it's own local database, it still is storing counter somewhere that is unknown to me.

I've already tried restarting everything.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa application downloads and runs its own copy of Mongo if it cannot be reached locally. Vargant is a virtual system and it probably creates new environment with separated network interface. You can force Opa application to use some other Mongo URL with parameter: `--db-remote IP_WHERE_MONGO_RUNS:27017`. Just find out how to contact your Windows' network interface from Vargant virtual environment.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to find the address for Windows from vagrant. Where does Opa store its own copy? Is there a way to clear it? I've cleared files from /vagrant/.opa/mongo

Comment: Thanks for the help, using the proper address worked. Forgot that localhost on the VM was different than on Windows. Still though, do you happen to know where opa stores that local database?

Comment: These files are in Linux in `YOUR_HOME_FOLDER/.opa/mongo` and in Vagrant it is probably what you found, but Opa application tries to download MongoDB if it is missing there each time it runs Mongo. Database files are stored in `~/.opa/mongo/data`, DBMS in `~/.opa/mongo/mongodb-VERSION_OF_MONGO_DISTRIBUTION`